# validator method not work in the JSF custom composite components

Tags: jsf, methods, validation, composite-component

JSF custom composite components
input.xhtml

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="validator"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText validator="#{cc.attrs.validator}"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

*.xhtml

```
<l:input value = ... validator="#{testValidator.validator}"/>
```

java code

@ManagedBean

public class TestValidator {

```
    public void validator(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
         System.out.println("Call validator");
    }
}
```

PropertyNotFoundException:

```
validator="#{testValidator.validator}": The class 'TestValidator' does not have the property 'validator'.
```

How to solve this problem?
my final way:

Comment: my final way: 
<cc:attribute name="validator" method-signature="void Action(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent,Object)"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed not going to work. In order to attach a validator to an input component specified by the composite, you need to register the input component as a  [`<cc:editableValueHolder>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/editableValueHolder.html) in the `<cc:interface>` first.

```html
<cc:interface>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="yourInputName" targets="yourInputId" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="yourInputId" ... />
</cc:implementation>
```

This way, any `<f:validator for="yourInputName">` nested in the composite component declaration will be applied to the desired input component.

```
<l:input>
    <f:validator validatorId="myValidator" for="yourInputName" />
</l:input>
```

You'll only need to replace the tight coupled validator method by a real standalone `Validator` implementation.

```
@FacesValidator("myValidator")
public class MyValidator implements Validator {
    // ...
}
```

Note: the standard JSF validators like `<f:validateLength>`, `<f:validateRequired>`, etc have all also a `for` attribute for this purpose.

Comment: thank you for your help,
   I need using method validator, without implements Validator and register id by '@FacesValidator('#{....}')'.
do you have any solutions, please help me.

Comment: You're asking for something which doesn't make sense nor is possible. Please note that I had a typo in my answer, the `@FacesValidator` name should not contain EL. If that was causing problems for you, then you can just fix it.

Comment: Thank you again,
my question is very useful for my application, and now, I found the solutions. please see follow key code:
        <cc:attribute name="validator" method-signature="void Action(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,
                      javax.faces.component.UIComponent,Object)"/>

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a cc:attribute "validator" with `targets` attribute:

```html
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="validator" targets="inputId"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="inputId"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

(Notice that I don't define validator attribute in h:inputText)

This is easy as long as you don't implement component class for your composite component. Well... even then it is easy, but it won't work if your component class extends `UIInput`. It works if it extends `UINamingComponent` class (I am not sure if this is the best solution, or if you can make it work with UIInput but it works).

So if you want to have your own component class try this one:

```
<cc:interface componentType="myComponent>
    <cc:attribute name="validator" targets="inputId"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="inputId"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

```java
@FacesComponent("myComponent")
public class MyComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    //your code here

}
```