# How to pass the validator method to a composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, customvalidator

I have my own inputText composite component created which wraps the p:inputText from Primefaces 3.4.5. It works well, but I can not figure out how to pass a bean validator method to the validator attribute in the p:inputText. I have read about using f:validator tags inside the composite component, but I really need to use the validator attribute on the p:inputText. The method and validation code works fine if I remove the composite component from my xhtml and just use a regular p:inputText.

My cc attribute is:

```
<composite:attribute name="validator" method-signature="void f(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,
                                     javax.faces.component.UIComponent,
                                     java.lang.Object)" targets="inputTextField"/>
```

my inputText inside the composite component is:

```
<p:inputText id="inputTextField"
 ... other attributes ...
validator="#{cc.attrs.validator}" />
```

when I use this composite component and pass a validator method to it, I get a property not found message...

```
Exception type: class javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
Exception message: /view/configuration/dictionaryupdate/DictionaryItem.xhtml @27,123        validator="#{dictionaryUpdateController.validateCode}": The class 'com.ntst.caremanager.feature.dictionaryupdate.controllers.DictionaryUpdateController' does not have the property 'validateCode'.
```

However, I do have that method defined in my view-scoped controller bean:

```
public void validateCode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
 ... code ....
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

I am using Mojarra 2.1.21

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [validator method not work in the JSF custom composite components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015462/validator-method-not-work-in-the-jsf-custom-composite-components)

Comment: Thank you. You are right. My mistake was adding the 'targets' attribute in the cc:attribute. Once I took that out everything worked.

Comment: @WanLi my solution is to add `targets` attribute in the cc:attribute, but do not declare validator attribute in the input field (see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39387222/1050460)